# Spring Security 2.0.6 Issues with Remember Me

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have gone through the steps to setup the remember me.

My understanding is that using this feature a cookie is created and when the user comes back to the browser and navigates to my site and the cookie has not expired that they should then be logged into my site.

I have verified that the cookie has been created, but I am never automatically logged into my site.

So I am a bit lost as to what needs to happen here - I have assumed that Spring Security takes care of this and that I do not need to extend any of their base classes - is that correct?

Here is the configuration I have so far:

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>


    <http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" access-denied-page="/login.jsp?login_error=2" >
      <concurrent-session-control max-sessions="1"  expired-url="/login.jsp"/>
      <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none"/>
      <intercept-url pattern="/styles/**" filters="none" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
      <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp?loggedout=true"/>
<!--      <remember-me key="ecotrak1q2w3e4r5tazsxdc"/>-->
    </http>
```

```
<beans:bean id="defaultTargetUrlResolver" class="org.springframework.security.ui.TargetUrlResolverImpl" />

<beans:bean id="roleBasedTargetUrlResolver" class="vsg.ecotrak.security.custom.CustomTargetUrlResolverImpl">
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="defaultTargetUrlResolver" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <custom-filter position="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER" />
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/admin/adminLanding.html"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp?login_error=1"/>
    <beans:property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="serverSideRedirect" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="targetUrlResolver" ref="roleBasedTargetUrlResolver" />
    <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" />

<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
    <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter">
  <custom-filter position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER" />
  <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />    
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsServiceWrapper"/>
  <beans:property name="key" value="ecotrak1q2w3e4r5tazsxdc"/>
</beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.providers.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
      <custom-authentication-provider />
      <beans:property name="key" value="ecotrak1q2w3e4r5tazsxdc"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Anything that needs to be done here?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the `custom-filter` position has not been specified for `rememberMe`.

```
<custom-filter position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER"/>
```

Comment: looks like I had missed that section in my original posting.  I have corrected.